# Minimizing the cost function for function that takes multiple arrays as inputs in Python

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have some function that takes in 4 1-D arrays as input and returns a single 1-D array as output.

```
def func(arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4):
    #function guts
    return answer
```

I am trying to get the output array of this function to match a pre-known correct array answer. I have made a cost function that can compare the function output to the actual answer, and give me a value representing how close it is (a lower number is better)

```
def cost_function(guess, real_answer):
   #function guts
   return cost      #lower number means guess is close to real answer
```

I would like a way to find the best values to use for the original input arrays to get close to the real answer. Presumably this will use the SciPy optimization package, but I am unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If your function output varies smoothly (small changes in input yield small changes in output) in all of its arguments, you could consider a gradient decent approach.

however, as you can see [here (scipy.optimize docs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html), there are also optimization methods you can select, that don't require prior knowledge, such as `powell`. What you will always need is a set of starting values and your function.

But consider: if you don't know much about `#function guts` and have a lot of parameters (your `arr1-4` have high dimensionality) then this will take a while...

hope this helps